# Embed html5 video in Template / Change image for video

Tags: html, image, for-loop, video

I'm new here and still learning how to write html and css. I'm making my portfolio from a template. Now I have some moving images I want to embed and used gif images. Only they get way too large, so I wanted to switch to html5 video.

Only when I change the `<img` to `<video` the whole gallery collapses. So I guess the css doesn't support html5 video.

This is the html right now:

```
<div class="ms-section__block">
          <div id="gallery">
            <img alt="image 2"
            src="assets/images/gallery/social/gif2.gif"
            data-description="image placeholder"> 
            <img alt="image 2"
            src="assets/images/gallery/social/gif2.gif"
            data-description="image placeholder"> 
            <img alt="image 2"
            src="assets/images/gallery/social/gif2.gif"
            data-description="image placeholder">
```

CSS MAIN:

```
.ms-section__block {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 88em;
    margin: 0 auto 6em;
```

This is the only thing I can find that is connected to the html code. 
But again. I'm a total noob and hope you guys can help me how to change the working `.gif` with `.mp4` to reduce file size.

Lucas

**The template i'm using is Emily - Creative Photography Portfolio**

Answer (score 0):

> Only when I change the `<img>` to `<video>` the whole gallery collapses.

It's not obvious what your problem is. All your posted code does is to put three items side-by-side. I can change one of those items to become a `<video>` tag. I cannot re-produce a collapse.

If the below code isn't what you need, then link an example page showing the "collapse" problem in action.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

.ms-section__block 
{
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 88em;
    margin: 0 auto 6em;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="ms-section__block">
    <div id="gallery">
    <img alt="image 2"
    src="assets/images/gallery/social/gif2.gif"
    data-description="image placeholder">

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="yourVideoFile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <img alt="image 2"
    src="assets/images/gallery/social/gif2.gif"
    data-description="image placeholder">

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```